# Using SSL when connection to server is not retaining

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, networking, ssl

I have a simple question - obviously SSL is an additional overhead and processing time, since there is bunch of stuff happening behind the scene when connecting, handshaking etc.

When connection is established and it is secure, you are good to go, BUT what about architectures when you can't(don't want to) simply retain the connection?

Imagine client connects to server, sends request, gets the response and immediately disconnects.

In this type of architecture SSL might add very significant overhead when connecting/disconnecting with each client request.

Please explain, what I am missing and what might be the alternative here?

Update from comments to make it clear:
I hope there is a clever solution for this, like session might be "remembered" and with next request not all the initial things will need to happen from scratch. So I hope to find an optimisation of SSL usage for not retaining connections.

Thank you All in advance!

Comment: You don't appear to be missing anything. I'm not quite sure what your question is though - you expect to get something like SSL's security level for free?

Comment: +1 for a good comment. I expect something clever done here.
Obviously with the todays mobile scale, it is reasonable to use not retaining connection architecture. I hope there is a clever solution for this, like session might be "remembered" and with next request not all the initial things will need to happen from scratch. So I hope to find an optimisation of SSL usage for not retaining connections - in short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC5077](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5077) (and prior to that, RFC4507) provide an extension for TLS "tickets" that allow for a shortcut renegotiation between client and server.  When initially connecting, the server can return a ticket that can be used for later connections.

It is possible the client and/or server don't support this, so in that case you fall back to the full negotiation each time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems this is what I was hoping to see with SSL implementations.
We can assume both server and client are under my control, so I should be able to add ticketing support to both.
Do you know proper way doing this? I hope OpenSSL will do all the work. Also is there any performance meagurements you are awear of?
Like ticketing vs. full negotiation.
I will mark this as answered after some more research.
Thanks again for a good answer!

Comment: Check SSL_OP_NO_TICKET for OpenSSL, which I believe is on by default but some libraries (e.g. libCURL) disable in their default set of options.  We did some measurements on this, and the improvement for throughput was quite noticeable.

Comment: Great to know, answered fully. I will try playing with it and update this if anything to share. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

SSL has a session feature which means that multiple connections can use the session negotiated by the first of them. The handshake when rejoining is considerably less expensive than the initial handshake (or a re-handshake that creates a new session).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Have a look here:
http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-session-reuse-rfc5077.html

Ticketing is preferred over session ids since with tickets server don't need to maintain server side cashes.

Comment: I'm aware of that. You need to be aware that session IDs are built in to TLS, and supported by most implementations. RFC 5077 is an extension, not supported by several major implementations.